Topological spaces in which countable intersections of dense open sets have dense interior
In certain topological spaces, known as Baire spaces (e.g., completely metrizable spaces), a countable intersection of dense open sets is dense.
Now consider the following strengthening of the Baire property (let's temporarily call it “super Baire”): “a countable intersection of dense open sets has dense interior” (edit: to clear up a possible confusion, “dense” here means “dense in the whole space”; equivalently, “a countable union of nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense”, where “nowhere dense” means the closure has empty interior; reformulated: “a meager set is nowhere dense”).
An example of a topological space with this “super Baire” property is the real line with the density topology (because nowhere dense sets for the density topology are exactly the Lebesgue nullsets; see Tall, “The Density topology“, Pacific J. Math. 62 (1976) 275–284, theorem 2.7).  Conversely, the real line with its usual (Euclidean) topology is Baire but not “super Baire” because the intersection of the open sets $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{r_n\}$ where $r_n$ ranges over all rationals, is the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ of irrationals, which has empty interior.
Questions: Does this “super Baire” property have a standard name?  Where might I learn more about it, or where might I find more examples of “super Baire” spaces?
Remarks (added in edit, 2024-08-04):

Following a comment by “Not Mike”, I should have remarked that the “super Baire” notion I am asking about is reminiscent of the notion of “P-space”, which is a space in which a countable intersection of open sets is open (for facts about P-spaces, see this MO answer by Joseph Van Name to Countable intersections in topological space and the paper by Misra, “A Topological view of P-spaces”, General Topology App. 2 (1974) 349–362).  But the notions are distinct: the density topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is “super Baire” but is not a P-space (because the intersection of the open — hence density-open — intervals from $-\frac{1}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n}$ is $\{0\}$ which is not density-open); and I don't see a reason why a P-space should be super Baire (but neither do I see a counterexample).

The “super Baire” property of $X$ seems equivalent to the assertion that the topos of sheaves on $X$ satisfies: $(\forall n:\mathbb{N}.\neg\neg P(n)) \Rightarrow (\neg\neg\forall n:\mathbb{N}.P(n))$ (“double-negation shift”) internally.  Maybe this is relevant.

Noé de Rancourt pointed out to me the following fact on Twitter: the set $[\mathbb{N}]^\infty$ of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with the Ellentuck topology (i.e. the topology generated by the sets $[s, M] = \{N \;|\; s \sqsubseteq N ⊆ M\}$, where $s$ is finite, $M$ infinite, and $\sqsubseteq$ means “initial segment”).  This is a consequence of Ellentuck's proof of Silver's theorem: every analytic subset of $[\mathbb{N}]^\infty$ is Ramsey.  See for instance the book Introduction to Ramsey spaces by Stevo Todorcevic, section 1.4, for more detail: the “super Baire” property of the topology follows from lemma 1.53 (p. 23) there.



Update (2024-08-05): The discussion has become a little bit confused because a number of similar statements have been mentioned so that we are (or at least, I am), lost in a maze of twisty little topological properties, all alike.  Let me summarize:

The original Baire property: “a countable intersection of dense open sets is dense”.

The property I am asking about, and which I am provisionally calling “super-Baire”: “a countable intersection of dense open sets has a dense interior” (where “dense” means “dense in the whole space”).

The property mentioned under the name “property P” by YCor in a comment, but which is called “almost P-space” in the paper “P-spaces and the Volterra property” by Santi Spadaro: “a nonempty countable intersection of open sets has a nonempty interior” (equivalently: every if $E$ is a $G_\delta$ then the interior of $E$ is dense in $E$).

The property of being a P-space mentioned in the first of my remarks above: “a countable intersection of open sets is open” (i.e., every $G_\delta$ is open).


Obvious implications are: (2)⇒(1) and (4)⇒(3).  Furthermore, (1)∧(3)⇒(2) (because if $E$ is a countable intersection of dense open sets, then (1) ensures that $E$ is dense in the whole space, and (3) ensures that the interior of $E$ is dense in $E$).
The usual topology on the real line satisfies (1) but neither (2) nor (3) nor (4).  The density topology on the real line satisfies (1) and (2) but neither (3) nor (4).  The Stone-Čech remainder (corona) $\mathbb{N}^* := \beta\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ of a discrete countable set satisfies (1), (2) and (3) but not (4).

It's been awhile, but I believe what you have described is adjacent to (or possibly equivalent to) the notion of P-space.

@NotMike Indeed, I should have mentioned the P-space property. I added a remark to the question on this subject.

Note: there is a (closely?) related notion, say "Property P": every nonempty $G_\delta$ subset has nonempty interior. It occurs in the following theorem of ZFC+CH due to Parovicenko: if $X$ is a Stone space with Property P, no isolated point, and with continuum many clopen subsets, then it is homeomorphic to $\beta\omega-\omega$ (the Stone-Cech remainder of a countable discrete set).

In the context of forcing or general properties of Boolean algebras, the exact phrasing you have is equivalent to being $\omega_1$-distributive. Perhaps something along the lines of $\omega_1$-Baire would be a good choice.

@NotMike: Good observation. The property of $\omega^*$ mentioned in YCor's comment is, in general, equivalent to the algebra of regular open sets being countably closed, which is a little stronger than being $\omega_1$-distributive.

Another example would be that any hyperstonean space $X$ has this “super Baire” property, as nowhere dense sets in $X$ are exactly those sets which are null w.r.t. any normal measure on $X$.

Yesrerday immediate after the  first version of  your  question I commented on your  question but unfortunately  I can not find  my  comments. any  way  my  comment was identical to my  existing  answer

@AliTaghavi I do remember seeing a comment of yours regarding a translation in terms of essential ideals (and I read it). I don't know how or why it disappeared.

Me  too I  do not  know how  or  why it disappeared

@YCor The “property P” you mention appears to be known as being an “almost P-space” by some people. I added an update to the question summarizing what I can say about some of the properties mentioned so far.

@NotMike Does this mean that the Stone space of an $\omega_1$-distributive Boolean algebra will be “super Baire” in the sense defined in the present question?

@Gro-Tsen Yes. They are dual notions.

@NotMike Is the precise statement you are referring to proposition 5.5.2 of chapter 17 in the Handbook of Boolean Algebras (screenshot here)? I ask because this one has “open dense” in the conclusion, which is different from “dense interior” in general (but maybe it's equivalent in the context of Boolean algebras / Stone spaces, I'm not too familiar with it). If you have the time, I would be grateful if you could write an answer with whatever equivalents of “super Baire” you can provide for Stone spaces.

Let $X$ be  a  compact  Hausdorff topological  space  put $A=C(X)$ the  $C^*$  algebra
of  all  complex  valued  continuous functions.
The  Gelfand  correspondence between  the  category  of compact  Hausdorff  spaces  and the  category of  commutative  unital  $C^*$  algebras leads us  to  a  dictionary containing the  following:(The  Gelfand  functor  maps  $X$  to  $C(X)$)
An  ideal  correspond  to an open  set since  for  an  open  set $U$ one  may  consider the  $I_U$ as the  ideal of  all  continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ such that the  support of  $f$ is  contained  in $U$.  An  open
dense set correspond  to  an  essential ideal
Recall that an  essential ideal in an  algebra $A$ is  an  ideal  $I$ with $I\cap J\neq \{0\}$  for  every  non  zero ideal $J$.
The property  you  mentioned,  a  stronger  version of the Baire  property, is  equivalent to the following:

Let $I_n$ be a sequence of  essential ideals   in $A=C(X)$ then $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$  is  an  essential ideal in $A$

This  property  can  be counted as  non  commutative  analogy  of the  strong  Baire  property  you  indicated to
An  advanced version of the   dictionary I  indicated  to is mentioned  here  in Dictionary  between  commutative  and  non  commutative  geometry  and  topology
Update 2024-08-07 One  application of the idea of  investigation of the OP  question via  Gelfand correspondence between the  category of commutative  $C^*$  algebras and  the  category of  compact  Hausdorff spaces is the following:
As we see in the  original question there is  no any Hausdorff  assumption. So one may pick  a  compact not necessarilly Hausdorff space $X$ which satisfies the  super  Baire  property. Then check if the  Hausdorfization $\tilde{X}$ of  $X$  is  again  a  super  Baire  space or  not.
I  explain about the  Hausdorfization of  a  compact  (not necessarily Hausdorff)  space: Let $X $ be  a  compact topological  space. Then $C(X)$ is a unital  $C^*$  algebra. Then  according  to the  Gelfand  duality explained above there is  a  unique (up to homeomorphism)  compact  Hausdorff topological space $\tilde{X}$ such that $C(X)$ is  $C^*$ isomorphic to $C(\tilde{X})$. The  space $\tilde{X}$ obtained in this way is  called the  Hausdorfization of $X$.
It can be shown that the  Hasdorfization $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ can be obtained as  follows: We define an equivalent relation on $X$: $a\sim b$ if  for  every  continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ we necessarilly have $f(a)=f(b)$. The  quotien space  $\frac{X}{\sim}$ is the  Hausdorfization of $X$ hence  $\frac{X}{\sim}$  is a  continuous open image of $X$. This  implies that  if $X$ is a  super  Baire space then its  Hausdorfization is a
super  Baire  space too.  Because an open  continuous image  of  a super  Baire space is  a Baire  space.

I understand that the property “the intersection of a sequence of essential ideals is an essential ideal” is an algebraic reformulation of the topological condition I wrote down. But is it a standard condition on C*-algebras? Does it appear anywhere? Does it perhaps have a name? Or are you just indicating an equivalent formulation?

@Gro-Tsen  I  do  not  know if it is apeared  somewhere or  not? But  many  years  ago  i was  thinking to NC analogy of  Baire  property  but  i  disappointed  since  every  compact  Hausdorf  space is already  a  Baire space . After  you posed  your  question I reallized that the  NC analogy  is that  a  countable intersection of  Essential ideals  must  be  an  essential  ideal. Note that in C[0,1]  a  countable intersection of  essential  ideals  can be the trivial ideal. Obviously [0,1]  does not  satisfies your  property

I don't understand how this is supposed to be relevant to @Gro-Tsen's original question. Why are you translating it into a statement about Cstar algebras? All you have done is reformulated the property that Gro-Tsen originally named.

@Gro-Tsen I am a functional analyst and this reformulation of the property you are asking about is not something I have seen in the Cstar context. Personally I don't think that the Gelfand-Naimark dictionary is going to help with either of the questions that you explicitly mention. What it might do is to stimulate people who work with Cstar algebras to find NC versions of the property under consideration; it is open whether this would lead to anything interesting

@YemonChoi  "All you have  done  is a reformulated..."  Ok  his  question is :"Is there a  name  for  this  property?  So  Yemon  what is  the job of a  dictionary translating a  name  or  a  word  into  another  language. So I  do not  see why is not  a relevant answer to (the  first  edition of ) the OP question. Moreover after that I post the  answer  I  found  some papers  who  concern if an intersection of essential ideals is  an essential ideal or  not.  (In case of  rings)

@Gro-Tsen  May  I ask  you to add some  tags  as  NCG  or  operator algebras or  functional  analysis. This  is  apparently unrealated to your question but in reality it is related to the  subject

If we’re dealing with NC version of this, it might be better to replace essential ideals with “essential left ideals” (defined by a left ideal $L \subset A$ is essential if $aL = 0$ implies $a = 0$ for all $a \in A$. Or equivalently if $L \cap R \neq {0}$ for any nonzero right ideal $R \subset A$), as there might not be many two-sided ideals in supply.

As I mentioned in comments, any hyperstonean space has the super Baire property, so any abelian vNa has this property. I wonder if all vNa satisfy the NC version.

@DavidGao Since a manifold do  not satisfy the super Baire property so it would be interesting to examin an appropriate NC analogy of the super Baire in an spectral triple

@DavidGao  One  may keep  commutativity  but  drop the involution   $*$ . That is  "Banach  algebras"

I just realized my NC version is a bad definition. Per this definition, any left ideal in a factor is essential, so unless the factor in question is just $\mathbb{C}$, it’s never going to be “super Baire” under this definition. The better definition is probably a left ideal $L \subset A$ is essential if $La = 0$ implies $a = 0$ for all $a \in A$. Though there doesn’t seem to be an equivalent characterization using intersections with other ideals anymore.

@AliTaghavi I don’t see any reason why studying this property in a commutative Banach algebra setting is interesting. And in the NC case, dropping the involution will make the left essential ideal definition and the corresponding right essential ideal definition no longer necessarily equivalent, so you would end up with a “left super Baire” property and a “right super Baire” property, which seems unsatisfactory to me. I don’t see much point in generalizing beyond $C^\ast$ algebras at all, but if you want to do it, I’d suggest just dropping the $C^\ast$ identity to study Banach $\ast$-algebras.

@DavidGao   Regarding  commutative  Banach  algebra I  would  suggest the  following point:  let A  and  B  be two Banach  algebras with super  Baire  property(In terms of essential ideal  intersection). Is it true to  say that every kind of tensor product $A\otimes B$ is  a  super baire  algebra?  This  is inspired by that fact that the product of  two  compact  baire  space  is  again  a  baire  space. On the other hand  we  pose this  question in commutative  C^* algebras we  have  an obvious "Yes"  but  if  we  drope the  commutativity we have  diffoculty with two  sided  ideals...

. So  a possible remedy is  consideration of  commutative  Banach  algebras

@Gro-Tsen  What  can be  said about the  topological dimension of  spaces you  examined(The space with  super  Baire  property)?Are there  plenty of  low  dimensional cases?

@DavidGao   from the  view of  dimension  theory one  may think  of  possible  low dimensional examples of  Banach  algebra  with desired property. I mean dimension in terms of  tsr and  real rank(M. Riefell's  work)

@DavidGao  So contrary to your opinion I think the  commutative  Banach  algebraic  setting is  interesting

@AliTaghavi In all honesty I still don’t find it interesting. The NC $C^\ast$ algebra version is at least motivated by understanding the theory of $C^\ast$ algebras as noncommutative topology. I’m not sure what motivates the version in commutative Banach algebras. I suppose the question on tensor products is at least nontrivial, but it still feels unmotivated to me. Then again, I don’t do much research in Banach algebras, so it might be simply that I’m not inclined towards this topic in the first place. To each their own, I suppose.

@DavidGao  One  another points with  classical  formulation but motivation from extension theory in  algebra:

@Gro-Tsen  let  X  be  a  topological  space $X=G \sqcup F$  $G$ open $F$  closed such that both $G, F$ satisfy  super  Baire. Does  this  imply that $X$ is  a  super  Baire

Motivation:  Let  two  algebra  $A,C$ satisfy the property  P  and we have  a  short exact  sequence $0\to  A\to B\to C\to 0$ does it  implies that B satisfies P  too?
